# What role is 一面 playing in "床は一面血まみれだった"?

Tags: translation, nuances, adverbs

The sentence

> 床は一面血まみれだった。

apparently translates to

> The floor was covered with blood.

**Question:** What role is 一面 playing in this sentence?

It seems to me that if we omitted that word entirely, the sentence would still be translated as something like: "As for the floor,  it was covered in blood".  So what role is 一面 playing (grammatically, and meaning wise)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[It's being used adverbially](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%B8%80%E9%9D%A2/#jn-12834), and emphasises that the *whole surface* was covered in blood. Perhaps you can imagine a floor which was 血まみれ ("bloodstained") but not covered from edge to edge in blood — this emphasises the completeness of the coverage, for dramatic effect.

Comment: According to my dictionary 一面 is a noun. Is it common in Japanese for nouns to be used as  adverbs? EDIT: I just checked an additional dictionary and there it was marked as a noun and an adverb.

Comment: @George Actually, you are right to be confused, as almost all monolingual dicts including the one linked in this answer do *not* list this usage as adverbial (they only list the 別の面 or ある側面 meaning for adverbial usage). The only monolingual dict which explicitly mentions this adverbial usage is 明鏡国語辞典: ❸広がったものの全体。そのあたり一帯。
「野山には一面に春の景色が広がる」
「あたり一面火の海だ」
［参考］副詞的にも使う。